# Additional examples of classes of networks whose Hasse diagram of the poset is a perfect graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, order-theory, posets, random-graphs

This question is very important for my research, which is why I ask it here.
I do not have a formal background in graph theory so please excuse me if I state a term incorrectly (and feel free to correct me).

Suppose I have a directed acyclic network with a source node $s$ and a sink node $t$. Suppose I construct a corresponding partially ordered set as follows:

1. The elements of the partially ordered set are edges of the directed acyclic graph.
2. Elements are comparable in the sense that two elements are comparable if there is an $s-t$ path between the two edges in the network. For example, $1 \preceq 2 \preceq 3$ means that there is an $s-t$ path consisting of edges $e_{1}$,$e_{2}$, $e_3$ in that order.
3. Thus, the maximal chains of the partially ordered set are the $s-t$ paths of the directed acyclic network.

Consider the Hasse diagram of the partially ordered set described above. Although, a Hasse diagram is technically a diagram not an undirected graph, we consider it as an undirected graph.

**My Question** **then is: For what general classes or types of networks or directed acyclic graphs (the directed version is acyclic) is the corresponding Hasse diagram, associated with the partially ordered set, a perfect graph?**

Recall, a graph is a perfect, by the Strong Perfect Graph Theorem, if is neither is not contains an induced odd cycle or antihole of length $5$ or more.

I believe, that series-parallel networks are one type of network which fit the above description. That is, the Hasse diagram is perfect of such networks.

I believe this is the case because there is no fence or zig-zag in the Hasse diagram corresponding to the poset associated with Series-Parallel networks (or at least there is some relation there).
See:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fence_(mathematics).

Interestingly, as wikipedia describes, a partially ordered set is series-parallel if and only if it does not have four elements forming a fence. Perhaps, the reason then the Hasse diagram is perfect is because it has no induced $P_4$. (I think there is a relation between "fence" in the poset and no induced $P_{4}$ of the corresponding Hasse diagram).

These are just some thoughts, I am not completely sure if what I have said is correct.

Of course, a graph can be perfect even if it has an induced $P_4$ (although if it does not have an induced $P_4$ then it is perfect).

**My question then remains, what is another example of directed acyclic graphs, or networks, besides series-parallel, where the corresponding Hasse diagram of the poset is a perfect graph?**

I feel that there should exist another class of such graphs but I have been unable to find one after a long time scouring the internet. Since I am not a researcher in graph theory, it has been really tough for me to find such a class of dag's or networks.

**If another class of directed acyclic graph or networks does not exist, does there exist an example of a class of directed cyclic graph with the above properties?**

Note, in the above questions, I am looking for classes of graphs, not a particular instance.

This question is very crucial for my research and I really appreciate any thoughts, guidance, or just anything at all that could at least point me in the right direction as I have been stuck for quite some time.
thanks.

Comment: Probably these are trivial examples for your purposes, but don't fences themselves qualify as posets whose Hasse diagrams are perfect graphs?